# create-react-app not working in my system

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, create-react-app

When i try to create my react project it shows an error log

```
C:\Users\Ezhil & rishii>npx create-react-app firstapp
'rishii\AppData\Roaming\npm\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Ezhil \node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

this was the error log shown in my cmd

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the npm path might be because of the space in the username ("Ezhil & rishii"). To solve it, go to a folder that doesn't have spaces in its name and run the command again.
Here's the example:

```
 cd C:\Users\Ezhil_rishii // use the directory name like this
npx create-react-app firstapp
```